# Trying to execute a dynamic pivot in pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I am trying to execute a dynamic pivot in pl sql.
This is what I have done so far

```
DECLARE
  col_names VARCHAR2(4000);
  pivot_table VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG('''' || base_name || '''', ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY base_name)
  INTO col_names
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT base_name FROM vfact_basis WHERE vfact_id = 'CA000123-2822') t;

  pivot_table := 'WITH base_value AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT vfact_base_period.vfact_id, amount, base_name
      FROM VFACT_BASE_PERIOD
      INNER JOIN VFACT_BASIS ON VFACT_BASE_PERIOD.VFACT_ID = VFACT_BASIS.VFACT_ID AND VFACT_BASE_PERIOD.BASE_ID = VFACT_BASIS.BASE_ID
      WHERE VFACT_BASE_PERIOD.VFACT_ID = ''CA000123-2822''
    )
    PIVOT (
      SUM(amount)
      FOR base_name
      IN (' || col_names || ')
    )
  )
  select * from base_value';

  dbms_output.put_line(pivot_table);
  
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE pivot_table;

END;
/
```

Everything runs as it should and when I copy and paste the string contained in col_names it runs how it should. However when I run this Query nothing shows up other then the put_line statement. It does not seem like the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement is working or doing anything.

I am expecting this query to be run and the resulting table to be outputted.

```
WITH base_value AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT vfact_base_period.vfact_id, amount, base_name
      FROM VFACT_BASE_PERIOD
      INNER JOIN VFACT_BASIS ON VFACT_BASE_PERIOD.VFACT_ID = VFACT_BASIS.VFACT_ID AND VFACT_BASE_PERIOD.BASE_ID = VFACT_BASIS.BASE_ID
      WHERE VFACT_BASE_PERIOD.VFACT_ID = ''CA000123-2822''
    )
    PIVOT (
      SUM(amount)
      FOR base_name
      IN (' || col_names || ')
    )
  )
  select * from base_value';
```

Comment: add all tables as create table with data to make a [mre]

Comment: `execute immediate` isn't going to print anything to the screen, it's just going to execute the query and discard the results.  Depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, my guess is that you may want to open a sys_refcursor and return that to the calling application which knows how to display the results of an arbitrary query by interrogating the metadata for the results.  If you're using `SQL*Plus`, you could create a cursor variable and use the `SQL*Plus` `print` command to print it after executing your block.

Comment: The sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause is pointless and can be removed so that you just have the `SELECT` statement contained in the `WITH` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am expecting this query to be run

The query is being run by `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

> and the resulting table to be outputted.

You are not asking for it to be output anywhere; so it is being run but you don't output it so of course you will not see anything.

If you want to display it then you need to either:

1. Use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE your_query BULK COLLECT INTO a_collection_variable;` and then loop through that collection and print it to the console using `DBMS_OUTPUT`;
2. Use a cursor loop and print each row of the output to the console using `DBMS_OUTPUT`;
3. On later versions that support it, use `DBMS_SQL` and `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`; or
4. If you are using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, you could create a cursor bind variable and then open that cursor for your dynamic SQL and then use the client-side `print` command to display the result set from the cursor (but that only works for certain client applications; there may be equivalent solutions for different client applications using their own syntaxes).